# Symfony rest api error with security.yaml

Tags: api, rest, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle, symfony6

I'm trying to add an auth system with JWT to my REST API but since I added my system and modified my `security.yaml` I have those errors:

[image: error]

[image: security.yaml]

Answer (score 0):

make sure of the alignments .. it can be spaces problem

```
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        guard:
            authenticators:
```

Comment: i had my security.yaml file above can you check?

Answer (score 0):

Lexik bundle doesn't require anymore guard with symfony 6